# @Test does not work in TestNG

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using TestNG to report but when I try to create a method for testing, eclipse displays the message: Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement.
The eclipse prompts you to insert a semicolon at the end of the method's parentheses.

```
public class ExtentReports3 {

ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
ExtentReports extent;
ExtentTest test;

@BeforeTest
public void startReport() {
    
    htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/test-output/MyOwnReport.html");
    extent = new ExtentReports();
    extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
    
    extent.setSystemInfo("Sistema Operacional", "Windows 10");
    extent.setSystemInfo("Host Name", "");
    extent.setSystemInfo("Enviromment", "QA");
    extent.setSystemInfo("User Name", "Leandro Pereira");
    
    htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("AutomationTesting.in Demo Report");
    htmlReporter.config().setReportName("My Own Report");
    htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.TOP);
    htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK);
    
    @Test
    public  void demoTestPass() {   
            test = extent.createTest("demoTestPass","This test will demostrate the PASS test case");
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
```

[Image erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSfeN.jpg)

[Image erro 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0bzc.jpg)

Comment: You are missing the closing curly brace from `startReport()`. It should be right before `@Test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put `@Test` inside `@BeforeTest` correct your code...e.g.

```
public class ExtentReports3 {

ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
ExtentReports extent;
ExtentTest test;

@BeforeTest
public void startReport() {

    htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/test-output/MyOwnReport.html");
    extent = new ExtentReports();
    extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

    extent.setSystemInfo("Sistema Operacional", "Windows 10");
    extent.setSystemInfo("Host Name", "");
    extent.setSystemInfo("Enviromment", "QA");
    extent.setSystemInfo("User Name", "Leandro Pereira");

    htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("AutomationTesting.in Demo Report");
    htmlReporter.config().setReportName("My Own Report");
    htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.TOP);
    htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK);
}
    @Test
    public void demoTestPass() {   
            test = extent.createTest("demoTestPass","This test will demostrate the PASS test case");
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
```